# Swift ¿Separación entres secciones UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Quiero hacer una lista de productos dividido entre vendedores, cada vendedor esta como una sección en la uicollectionview, el problema es que me va agregando mas separación entre cada una de las secciones y no sé por que.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
       //print(section)
       //(-6.5 - (CGFloat(section) * 12.5))
       return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
       return 0.0
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
       return 0.0
    }
```

[image: Separacion de las secciones]

Comment: Está en un TableView?

Comment: no es un collectionview

Comment: Y probaste cambiando los valores? Es decir un top: 20, bottom: 20? o los return con 2.0?

Comment: cambie los valores pero aun asi el espacio va aumentando entre cada seccion

Answer (score 0):

creo que te falta definir el size:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        let width = (screenSize.width-leftAndRightPaddings)/numberOfItemsPerRow
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }
```

tambien puedes probar reduciendo el espacio:

```
var collectionVisor = VisorImagesSource()

collectionVisor.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
collectionVisor.minimumLineSpacing = 0
```

Comment: si tengo agregado el size, cada row tiene 150 de height y el width es del tamaño del collectionview

Comment: @AntonioPacheco he editado mi respuesta